# Alphabetical sections in table table view

Tags: ios, swift, list, uitableview

I have a list of names sorted alphabetically, and now I want display these names in a table view. I'm struggling with grouping these names for each letter.

My code looks like this:

```
  class ContactTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var contactArray = ["Alan Douglas", "Bob", "Bethany Webster", "Casey Fleser", "Daniel Huckaby", "Michael Morrison"]
    var contactSection = [String]()
    var contactDictionary = [String : [String]]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        generateWordsDict()

        let nav = self.navigationController?.navigationBar
        nav?.tintColor = UIColor(red: 16.0, green: 18.0, blue: 34.0, alpha: 1.0)
        nav?.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func generateWordsDict(){
        for contact in contactArray {

            let key = "\(contact[contact.startIndex])"
            let lower = key.lowercased()

            if var contactValue = contactDictionary[lower]
            {
                contactValue.append(contact)
            }else{
                contactDictionary[lower] = [contact]
            }
        }
        contactSection = [String](contactDictionary.keys)
        contactSection = contactSection.sorted()
    }
    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
         return contactSection.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForFooterInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return contactSection[section]
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        let contactKey = contactSection[section]
        if let contactValue = contactDictionary[contactKey]{
        return contactValue.count
        }
        return 0
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellContact", for: indexPath)

        let cotactkey = contactSection[indexPath.section]

        if  let contactValue = contactDictionary[cotactkey.lowercased()] {

            cell.textLabel?.text = contactArray[indexPath.row]

            cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
        }
        return cell
    }
    override func sectionIndexTitles(for tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {
        return contactSection
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, sectionForSectionIndexTitle title: String, at index: Int) -> Int {
        guard let index = contactSection.index(of: title) else {
            return -1
        }
        return index
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
         self.tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }
 }
```

and it all works pretty good except for the grouping which makes my table view end up like this:

[image]

I wanted to do something like this:

[image]

but I do not know how to implement:

> How to adjust the color of the letters? how to make a list of names to
>   display correctly?

Comment: In Objective c you can do like ->`- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {    

  for(UIView *view in [tv subviews])
  {
    if([[[view class] description] isEqualToString:@"UITableViewIndex"])
    {

      [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
      [view setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]];
    }
  }

  //rest of cellForRow handling...

}`

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28087688/alphabetical-sections-in-table-table-view-in-swift

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `cellForRowAt` You need to use `contactValue` instead of `contactArray`.

**Change line**

```
cell.textLabel?.text = contactArray[indexPath.row]
```

**To**

```
cell.textLabel?.text = contactValue[indexPath.row]
```

Also instead of `titleForFooterInSection` you need to implement `titleForHeaderInSection`.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return contactSection[section].uppercased()
}
```

To change the Section title color to `white` implement `willDisplayFooterView` method.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayFooterView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    if let view = view as? UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
        view.textLabel?.textColor = .white
    }
}
```

Change `sectionIndexBackgroundColor` property of `tableView` to color that you want instead of `white` color.

```
self.tableView.sectionIndexBackgroundColor = .black
```